# HDMI output not showing up for Radeon RX580 GPU

Tags: sound, hdmi, radeon, settings

I have an RX580 GPU connected to a monitor (AORUS FO48U) with built-in speakers that works fine with intel iGPU.

When I use the AMD GPU, I can not select an HDMI Audio device in the settings.

[image]

The only output that can be selected is Digital Output S/PDIF Built-in Audio.

Audio Info:

```
$ inxi -A
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Ellesmere HDMI Audio [Radeon RX 470/480 / 570/580/590]
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-58-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

Graphics info:

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: AMD Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]
    driver: amdgpu v: kernel
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: amdgpu,ati
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,radeon,vesa gpu: amdgpu
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: AMD Radeon RX 580 Series (polaris10 LLVM 15.0.6 DRM
    3.42 5.15.0-58-generic)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.2.5
```

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

GPU: RX580

Driver: Open Source amdgpu

CPU: 12600k

Display: AORUS FO48U

The dmesg only shows inputs found?

```
$ dmesg  | grep -i hdmi
[    0.157772] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    3.898404] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input14
[    3.898424] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input15
[    3.898438] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input16
[    3.898460] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input17
[    3.898474] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input18
[    3.898486] input: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input19
```

### Update

During boot, the kernel reports:

```
snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: bound 0000:01:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
```

Comment: i have the very same problem. RX580 was perfectly fine untill i upgrade the version to 22.04. any fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that Windows 10 is not able to use HDMI audio output either, I am calling this a device limitation.

It's disappointing that AMD RX580 just can't do audio out on HDMI.

[image]

Comment: I've got many many problems with audio on Ubuntu and cannot get it to work either at the moment. However, the idea that RX580 cannot perform sound output is entirely wrong; I've been running it for multiple years (but system updates sometimes break the functionality, like it did now).